# how to increase box width with animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to animate a box width from 20px to 80px, but only the right side of the box. so that mean the right side increase the width 60px with animation when i hover on it. what is the jquery code for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only CSS3 and HTML. No need to use jquery.

```css
.box {
        transition: 0.2s;
        width: 20px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color:#0066CC;
        position : absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
    }
    
    .box:hover {
        width: 80px;
        height: 100px;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer using Jquery

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="animate" align="left">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#animate").hover(function(){
$(this).animate({
width: "80px",
  }, 500 )
}, function(){
$(this).animate({
width: "20px",
  }, 500 )
});
```

Check at: http://jsfiddle.net/8nuoh4u4/

Comment: this one work too, thanks for telling me the jquery one

Comment: You're welcome :) - just take care that transition (css answer) may not work in non-css3 supporting browsers. That is where this will help. Cheers.